# UIViewController with many xibs

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am developing an iOS application. I have a controller : iPhonePopUpController, in this controller i have a xib like this image :[image]

My question is, can i add an other xib to this Controller and loaded it when i need it or should i create a second controller to load my second xib ? [image]

Comment: In this example, you are using storyboard, right?

Comment: For what purpose you are adding another xib. You can  add view on xib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load anything from a XIB using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourOtherXIB.xib" owner:someObjectThatWillTakeThePlaceOfFilesOwner options:0]
```

This line unarchive the XIB named `YourOtherXIB.xib` by creating the instances of the objects you have in your XIB, and then connect all the outlets and actions you defined in the XIB, and return the list of top-level objects.

---

When you create a XIB whose File's Owner is an `UIViewController`, typically you then initialize your `UIViewController` using code like this:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle] autorelease];
```

What this code basically do internally is that it stores the `nibName` and `bundle` you provide in some internal property, and when it needs to load its view (especially the first time it needs to display it onscreen), it loads the view from the XIB using something like the line quoted above:

```
[bundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:0];
```

As you connected the view in your XIB to the `view` IBOutlet of the `File's Owner`'s (which in that case is the `self` passed as an argument, namely the `UIViewController` itself), then the `view` property of your `UIViewController` will be populated with the view that has just been unarchived from the XIB. And that's how `UIViewController` loads its view from a XIB file.

But of course you can do the same for your own classes and do not need your File's Owner to be an `UIViewController`. Simply make your File's Owner be whatever class fits your need, expose a custom IBOutlet from this class and connect it to your objects in your XIB.

- For example you can have a `MyCustomClass` class that declares an `IBOutlet UIView* myOtherView;`. Define the class of your `File's Owner` in your XIB to be of the class `MyCustomClass`, then bind the `myOtherView` outlet to the view to load from your XIB. Then in the code, create an instance of `MyCustomClass` and use the above `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method by passing this `MyCustomClass` instance as the `owner` parameter
- Or you can reuse your `UIViewController` that loaded your primary XIB to load your other view from your secondary XIB too: simply add an `IBOutlet UIView* otherView` in your `UIViewController` subclass. In your first XIB, you will connect the `view` IBOutlet to your primary view but keep the `otherView` IBOutlet unconnected. In your second XIB, you will connect the `otherView` IBOutlet to your other view but keep `view` IBOutlet unconnected. When loading your `UIViewController` with the first XIB, the `view` property will be set to the view loaded from your XIB. Then if you want to lazy-load the `otherView` from the other XIB at a later time, simply call `loadNibNamed:owner:options` with `OtherXIB.xib` as the nib name and `self` as the owner. The `OtherXIB` will be unarchived and `otherView` property will be filled with that loaded view.